# __import__ or import_module vs import when chaining multiple django settings files

Tags: python, django, settings, django-settings

I'm trying to modularize my django settings file so that it's easier for to deploy and manage our multiple environments.

I've got it set up to load my files in this order...

1. settings.py - settings common to all
2. config/country_XX - settings specific to the install for that country (XX could be US, CA, AU, etc)
3. config/developer_XX - settings specific to a particular developer's local dev environment

Both the secondary files are allowed to change values set in previous files

I find that if 1 loads 2 and 3 using the normal

```
from config.country_XX import *
```

the changes I make in those files are preserved.

If, however, 1 loads 2 and 3 using

```
__import__()
```

or

```
importlib.import_module()
```

the changes I make are not preserved.

I'd prefer to use import_module because it allows me to write cleaner code

```
import_module('config.country_' + country)
```

instead of

```
if country = 'AA':
  from config.country_AA import *
elif: country == 'BB'
  from config.country_BB import *
...
```

Here's what I've got... let me know what you think.

settings.py

```
import os
import sys
from django.utils import importlib

DEVELOPMENT = True
DEBUG = False
USES_24_HOUR_TIME = True

country_config = 'config.country_us'
developer_config = 'config.developer_jack'
try:
    #importlib.import_module(country_config)
    from config.country_us import *

    if DEVELOPMENT:
        #importlib.import_module(developer_config)
        from config.developer_jack import *

except ImportError:
    pass
```

config/country_us.py

```
import sys
globals().update(vars(sys.modules['settings']))

USES_24_HOUR_TIME = False
```

config/developer_jack.py

```
import sys
globals().update(vars(sys.modules['settings']))

DEBUG = True
```

Comment: this is what got me started: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#Accessingandmodifyingexistingsettings